# Checkbox unchecked and div show

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 2 input checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  name="A" value="A" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"  name="B" value="B" checked="no">
```

and 2 divs

```
<div class="1">
   <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </p>
 </div>   
<div class="2">
   <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </p>
 </div>
```

The default will be checkbox 2 unchecked when checkbox 1 clicked, also only div 1 show 
and checkbox1 unchecked when checkbox2 clicked, then div 2 show and div 1 hide,
actualy what js code is proper with this issue, as i've tried it but it didn't work.

```
<script>
$j(document).ready(function(){
   $j("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $j("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", false);        
    }
    else {
        $j("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", true);       
    }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you use radio instead of checkbox..

Comment: i suggest you to use same name for two checkboxes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

               $('#checkbox1').prop("checked", true);
               //  $('#checkbox2').attr('disabled', true);
               $('.2').hide();
               $('#checkbox1').click(function () {
                   $('.2').hide();
                   $('.1').show();
                   $('#checkbox2').prop("checked", false);
                    $('#checkbox1').attr('disabled', true);
                     $('#checkbox2').attr('disabled', false);
               });
               $('#checkbox2').click(function () {
                   $('.1').hide();
                    $('.2').show();
                   $('#checkbox1').prop("checked", false);
                    $('#checkbox2').attr('disabled', true);
                     $('#checkbox1').attr('disabled', false);
               });

           });
```

It will give the result as you specified above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8svsq/). Update your JS to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#checkbox1").click(function() {
   $("#checkbox2").attr("disabled", this.checked);
 });
});
```

Comment: Sorry i modify the default condition @ishank-gupta

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
<script>
$j(document).ready(function(){
   $j("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
     var index = $j(this).attr('id').replace('checkbox','');
     var secondIndex = 2;          
     if(index == 2)
         secondIndex = 1;

     if(this.is(':checked'))
     {
       $j('.'+index).show();// show div related to checked checkbox

       $j('.'+secondIndex).hide(); // hide other div
       $j('#checkbox'+secondIndex).attr('disabled',true); // disable other checkbox          
     }
     else
    {
      // if checkbox unchecked
      $j('.'+index).hide();//hide div 1
      $j('.'+secondIndex).hide(); //hide div 2
      $j('#checkbox'+secondIndex).attr('disabled',false); // enable other checkbox
     } 
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i think `if (this.is(':checked))`has to be `if (this.is(':checked'))`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want it like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#checkbox1").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", true);        
    }
    else {
        $("#checkbox2").prop("disabled", false);       
    }
});

$("#checkbox2").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#checkbox1").prop("disabled", true);        
    }
    else {
        $("#checkbox1").prop("disabled", false);       
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the user to select the checkboxes simultaneously? If that is what you want, hope this code helps.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="A" value="A" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="B" value="B" disabled>
<div class="1" style="display:none">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
<div class="2" style="display:none">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.1').css('display', 'block');
        $("#checkbox1").change(function () {

            if (this.checked) {
                $('.1').css('display', 'block');
                $('#checkbox2').attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $('.1').css('display', 'none');
                $('#checkbox2').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
        $("#checkbox2").change(function () {

            if (this.checked) {
                $('.2').css('display', 'block');
                $('#checkbox1').attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $('.2').css('display', 'none');
                $('#checkbox1').attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

Demo:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75kDM/)

Hope it helps.